# Updating checked property with a value from select button in Tapestry

Tags: java, html, tapestry

For better understanding what I want to achieve here is an visual representation of my issue:

[image]

In the image above, I have a list of all tickets, status select button and Save button. Now when user wants to change( update ) status of tickets, he checks tickets and all checked tickets should be updated with a status from select button once user clicks on Save button.

My java code so far looks like this:

```
    /**
     *
     * @author
     */
    public class POS {

        @Inject
        private Request request;
        @Inject
        private BiznisLogika tiketDao;
        @Inject
        private Session session;
        @InjectComponent
        private Zone result;
        @SessionState
        @Property
        private SearchCriteria criteria;
        @SessionState
        @Property
        private SearchCriteriaTwo criteriaTwo;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Property
        private GridDataSource source = new TicketDataSource(session, Tiket.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Property
        private Tiket currentTicket;
        @Property
        @Persist
        private TiketStatus noviStatus;
        @Property
        private SelectModel tiketSelectModel;
        @Inject
        SelectModelFactory selectModelFactory;
        @Inject
        private Session hibernate;
        @Inject
        private GenericDao genericDao;

        void setupRender() {
            criteriaTwo = null;
            criteria = null;
        }

        private final class TicketDataSource extends HibernateGridDataSource {

            private TicketDataSource(Session session, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class entityType) {
                super(session, entityType);
            }

            @Override
            public int getAvailableRows() {
                return criteria.getSearchPattern() == null ? 0 : super.getAvailableRows();
            }

            @Override
            protected void applyAdditionalConstraints(Criteria crit) {
                crit.add(Restrictions.ilike("ticketSerial", criteria.getSearchPattern())).add(Restrictions.ilike("ticketDate", criteriaTwo.getSearchPattern()));
            }
        }

        void onValidateFromDelete() {
            // Unfortunately, this method is never called because Checkbox doesn't bubble up VALIDATE. It's a shame because
            // this would be the perfect place to validate whether deleting is OK, or to put an entry in deleteCopyByRowNum.
            // Please vote for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2075 .
        }
        // The Loop component will automatically call this for every row as it is rendered.

        public boolean isDelete() {
            return false;
        }

        // The Loop component will automatically call this for every row on submit.
        public void setDelete(boolean delete) {
        }

        @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.SUCCESS)
        Object searchTickets() {
            return request.isXHR() ? result.getBody() : null;
        }

        Object onAction() {

            return request.isXHR() ? result.getBody() : null;

        }

        public ValueEncoder<TiketStatus> getTiketStatusEncoder() {
            return new ValueEncoder<TiketStatus>() {
                @Override
                public String toClient(TiketStatus value) {
    // return the given object's ID
                    return String.valueOf(value);
                }

                @Override
                public TiketStatus toValue(String id) {
                    return TiketStatus.valueOf(id);
                    // return (Tiket) genericDao.getById(Tiket.class, Long.parseLong(id));
                }
            };
        }

        @CommitAfter
        Object onSaveThemAll() {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.getAvailableRows(); i++) {
                currentTicket.setTicketStatus(noviStatus);
                hibernate.merge(currentTicket);


            }
            return request.isXHR() ? result.getBody() : null;

        }

    }
```

And my tml code looks like this:

```
<t:layout t:pageTitle='${message:POS}' xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

    <form t:type="form" t:zone="result" t:id="searchForm" class="full-form" >

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label t:type="label" t:for="query">Buscar</label>
                </th>
                <td><input type="text" t:type="textfield" t:id="query" t:value="criteria.query" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" t:type="datefield" t:id="queryTwo" t:value="criteriaTwo.queryTwo" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label t:type="label" t:for="rowsPerPage">Resultados</label></th>
                <td><select t:type="select" t:id="rowsPerPage" t:value="criteria.rowsPerPage" t:model="literal:5,10,15,20"></select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-submit">
            <input style="color:black;" type="submit" t:type="submit" class="btn-active" value="Search" /> or <a href="#">cancel</a>
            <span t:trigger="searchForm" t:zone="result"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <t:form t:id="deletetables">
        <div t:type="zone" t:id="result" id="result" class="section result">
            <table t:type="grid" t:source="source" t:inPlace="true" t:add="ticketStatusUpdate" t:rowsPerPage="criteria.rowsPerPage" t:include="ticketSerial,ticketStatus, ticketNumber,ticketDate" t:row="currentTicket">
                <p:ticketStatusUpdateCell>
                    <t:form>
                        <input t:id="delete" t:type="checkbox" value="delete">
                        </input>
                    </t:form>

                </p:ticketStatusUpdateCell>
                <p:empty>
                    <p class="empty-result">${message:no-result}</p>
                </p:empty>

            </table></div>

        <t:select t:id="noviStatus" encoder="tiketStatusEncoder" style="color:black;" validate="required" >

        </t:select>

    <t:eventlink t:id="saveThemAll"> Save </t:eventlink>
    </t:form>

</t:layout>
```

Now I would like to know how can I achieve it, ie. how can I update each selected ticket with a new status pulled from t:select t:id="noviStatus" button.

P.S. I have checked this example on fabulous Tap e-learning website JumpStart, but I can't figure out how to implement it in my case.
http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/tables/gridwithdeletecolumn1

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to go about this, but I personally think the simplest way to handle this kind of thing is to add a transient value to your CurrentTicket object and set the value in your grid.

Example

```
@NonVisual
@Transient
private boolean delete;

//getters and setters
```

Then in the grid

```
<input t:id="delete" t:type="checkbox" value="currentTicket.delete">
```

When you submit the form you'll be able to iterate through your list of tickets and read the delete value.

The other way of doing it is to use a getter / setter for delete and save the delete boolean in some kind of a map with the object id.